# How to use a glb file in flutter web

Tags: flutter, 3d

i am using glb file in flutter web app but they show me this error.

i am use this library version model_viewer_plus: ^1.7.0

HTML generated for model_viewer_plus:

body,
    model-viewer {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    /* other-css */

Answer (score 0):

modify web/index.html to load JS in  tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).